# Is WebVR compatible with Hololens?

Tags: microsoft-edge, virtual-reality, hololens, webvr

When I open a WebVR website with Hololens, it tells me that Wdge is note compatible with WebVR. Is this an update problem or do I have to something else?

Or is Hololens not compatible with web vr?

Comment: However, you CAN run WebVR through Windows Mixed Reality Headsets (Acer) - works just fine! And Edge (gasp) does a pretty good job of supporting WebVR. Sample built barebones without framework at http://github.com/pindiespace/webvr-mini.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is necessary, but functionality has been added to support WebVR for the Hololens. You can read more about it [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-webvr-in-edge-with-windows-mixed-reality)

Answer (score -3):

HoloLens is "Mixed Reality" and WebVR (notice the 'VR'), is Virtual Reality. Two are completely different things, therefore are not compatible.

Comment: In this  (https://webvr.rocks/microsoft_edge#windows) website  they say that this (mixed reality acer headset) device si compatible. So I thought maybe it was just a matter of time. Thanks for your answer.